# WatchOS 3 openParentApplication?

Tags: swift, watchos-3

In my App, I communicate from iPhone to the Apple Watch and from the Apple Watch to the iPhone.

For a Tableview on Apple Watch, I receive the Data from the iPhone when the App is running on the iPhone, all is fine.

Now I implemented a Button on the Watch App and want to trigger the iPhone to reload the Data and send it to the Watch.

In WatchOS 1 is was made `wkInterfaceController.openParentApplication`
but in WatchOS3 this method is missing.

Now my question is how can I open the iPhone App for initiate the Datareload?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That method is deprecated and I have spent about a week researching about how to do this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619531-openparentapplication

You can use the new WCconnectivity library to communicate with the parent application to send messages, files, and images to the phone application and vice versa.